# iOS- Cannot get expected json results back

Tags: ios, json, http, rest

I am trying to use google currency rest api to get USD->GBP convert result.
something like this-> http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100USD=?GBP

the json is response is :
{lhs: "100 U.S. dollars",rhs: "62.9802242 British pounds",error: "",icc: true}

so i m trying to get the values from "lhs" "rhs" stored into 2 strings

here is my method for fetching converted result data :

```
@implementation ConvertorBrain

-(id)initWithFromCurrency:(NSString *)fromCurrency
               toCurrency:(NSString *)toCurrency
               withAmount:(int)amount
{
    if (self=[super init]) {
        self.fromCurrency = fromCurrency;
        self.toCurrency = toCurrency;
        self.amount = amount;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)getConvertResult
{
    NSString *encodeFromCurrencyTerm = [self.fromCurrency stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *encodeToCurrencyTerm = [self.toCurrency stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *searchLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=%d%@=?%@", self.amount, encodeFromCurrencyTerm, encodeToCurrencyTerm];
    NSURL *convertedResults = [NSURL URLWithString:searchLocation];

    NSData *JSONData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:convertedResults];
    if ([JSONData length] > 0) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary *dictoionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:0 error:&error];
        if (!dictoionary) {
            NSLog(@"Json parsing failed: %@", error);
        }

        self.lhs = [dictoionary valueForKey:@"lhs"];
        self.rhs = [dictoionary valueForKey:@"rhs"];

    } else {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Service Error" message:@"Cannot complete your request at this time, please try later" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}
```

then i called method in some other place like this :

```
self.brain = [[ConvertorBrain alloc] initWithFromCurrency:@"USD" toCurrency:@"GBP" withAmount:100];
[self.brain getConvertResult];
```

then my expected lhs and rhs results should be lhs= "100 U.S. dollars" rhs ="62.9802242 British pounds"

however, if i run the code, it throw me back these errors:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No string key for value in object around character 1.) UserInfo=0x7172860 {NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 1.}

i cannot figure out what has went wrong..need help, 
also, i tried to debug it a bit. it seems is this line went wrong, dosent get any data somehow -> `NSData *JSONData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:convertedResults];`

Comment: [IOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_IOS), [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS). Case matters.

Comment: Use a method of getting the data from the URL that returns an error to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL looks malformed. For example:
http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=50USD=?GBP

Within a browser that will work fine because the browser handles special characters automatically, but that ? at the end is invalid.

Try using this URL. Be sure to escape the % in the string by putting another % after it.
http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=50USD=%3FGBP

Here's some other character encodings: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Hm. Well, I threw together a simple app. It appears that the URL is fetched properly for me with code nearly identical to yours. The error message you are getting is from the JSON parser. It appears that the response from google is invalid (paste a response here: http://jsonlint.com/). You'll either have to parse the contents of the result yourself, or use a third-party JSON library that may be less strict about the JSON data. =\

Comment: ummm, still cannot get anything back to NSDATA... which 3td lib would u recommand me to use? or could u plz explain in a bit details how exactly "parse the contents of the result"? cheers

Comment: Are you positive you aren't seeing anything in the NSData object? Have you tried printing it to NSLog, prior to trying to deserialize it? I'm seeing it come through. Parse the contents of the result means selecting finding the pieces of data you are looking for in the request that you need. For example, using a Regular Expression to pull the lhs and rhs values instead of converting the string into objects. As for which third-party library, you'd have to experiment to see which ones will not have an issue. I'm not sure on that one =\

Answer (score 0):

Your json could be incorrectly formatted. Use this to check that your json is formatted correctly. http://jsonlint.com/